# redux-multistore project has no react dev-tools time travel

Tags: javascript, vue.js, redux, reactive-programming, redux-observable

folks,

I developed a library leveraging redux-observable and need your help.

I want to make it work with redux dev-tools time travel.

Is someone likely to join the team and help?

Please fork the project on github. You're welcome to contribute.

https://github.com/i-think-rapido/redux-multistore

Comment: Not an actual programming question at all - it's a request for assistance with a project.

Comment: Sorry for that, I was not specific enough.